# Sencha touch better practice for off then on on events

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I have a button in Sencha (touch) which in an action button. This button has a different function in each view. When I change the view the controller sets the correct function for the button:

```
myButton.on("click", function() {}); etc.
```

When I switch view I first need to call:

```
myButton.off("click");
```

and then I can bind the click again with:

```
myButton.on("click", function() {});
```

If I not call the off function both click events will fire. Is there a faster way to bind a new event and flush all the other bound events?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the methods addListener and removeListener, for example:

```
var myFunction = function () { };
myButton.addListener("click", myFunction);
myButton.removeListener("click", myFunction);
```

For this to work, you need to pass the same function object to both methods, that means you can't declare the function inline when calling addListener.

To remove all handlers is very easy:

```
myButton.clearListeners();
```

Comment: on/off does exactly the same since on is a shorthand for addListener.

Comment: Then you can use clearListeners() and it will remove all attached handlers.

Comment: Why isn't there a myButton.clearListeners('click'); function, is it technically hard to implement? I mean architecturally for Sencha Touch.